# Riak CS public ACL by default for new objects

Tags: riak, riak-cs

Is it possible to make Riak CS apply ACL with public access by default upon new bucket or file in some bucket created? I mean I wanna put files for example using simply

```
s3cmd put file.jpg s3://my-bucket
```

And I'd like to have file.jpg in my-bucket to be public accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean that "objects are anonymously readable" by "public
access"?  I will continue with the assumption that it is true.

Because ACL is per bucket or per object, bucket policy will be more
suitable for the use case.  After creating the bucket `my-bucket`, one
can set particular bucket policy through PUT Bucket Policy API [1].

Example policy JSON to allow public access to the bucket is like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1355283297687",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1355283289",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
            "Principal": { "AWS": ["*"] }
        }
    ]
}
```

Then you can PUT it with proper URL as API doc [1] by any means,
a simple way is to use `s3cmd` as

```
s3cmd setpolicy </path/to/above/json/as/file> s3://my-bucket
```

Then each object written under the bucket can be accessed by any user
including anonymous one.

Unfortunately there is no way to apply such bucket policy at creating
bucket but, I hope, it's not difficult to write wrapper script to
create bucket and apply policy to it.

[1] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketPUTpolicy.html